# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i made a function appendScript which will be called on a button click event my function code is

```
function appendScript()
{var v_js;
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      v_js = document.createElement('script');
    v_js.type = 'text/javascript';
v_js.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(v_js);
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
v_js =document.createElement('script');
v_js.type="text/javascript" ;
v_js.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js";

body.appendChild(v_js);
var v_css= document.createElement('link');
v_css.rel= "stylesheet";
v_css.type = "text/css" ;
v_css.href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css"
body.appendChild(v_css);
}
```

when i click on the button i am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function)
```

can any one please help how to resolve this error ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your version of JQuery(1.5.2) and Bootstrap (2.3.2) are not compatible. Upgrade your version of Jquery. Bootstrap is looking for `on()` which is not available in your version(1.5.2). `.on()` is available from version 1.7+ of jquery. So try upgrade it to the latest version as possible.

When you download the latest version of **[boostrap(2.3.2)](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/05/17/bootstrap-2-3-2-released/)** it provides you 1.9.1 version of jquery along with the package, so you may want to try upgrading at least to that version to ensure everything is working as expected.